# Big Green Men... from Earth

Tags: biology, humans, flora

There are a couple of stories where humans gain chloroplasts.

Here's a clip from [one story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_and_Choosers_(novel)):

> They are also infused with bacteriorhodopsin, allowing photosynthesis. It is now possible for a human being to lie on the ground, in the sunlight, for thirty minutes, and absorb all the energy and nutrients they need for a 24-hour period.

But, this strikes me as unlikely.  The other story had humans being powered by sunlight.

> While working with this idea we happened across an interesting and rather common tittle freshwater coelenterate named Hydra viridis. This particular hydra, unlike its relatives, exists in a symbiotic relationship with a wonderful alga called chlorella.
>
> In addition to producing its own food, it will also produce enough to
>   keep its host alive. "When chlorella is not present, the hydra is forced
>   to eat solid food just like its white relatives."
>
> ...will have to believe you after you've done nothing but sit in the sun and starve yourself tor weeks on end without getting hungry or losing any weight.

EDIT: removed 3 hours a day for power/meals, since the story didn't *clearly* say that, only implied it.

It sees to me that an animal running around needs a lot of sugar/energy.  Even if we take out the energy needed to process food (a non-trivial amount), it seems to me that a human would require more power than could be provided by merely having a green skin.  Square-cube law, and more mass behind a smaller surface area than a microscopic animal.

IIRC, humans need about 2,500-3,000 calories a day.

Working skin is a under a couple of layers of dead skin, which should impact how effective the chlorophyll would be (how much?)

**Assuming there was a way to prevent them from being liquidated and absorbed; how much energy would a bunch of chloroplasts within vacuoles in the human skin provide?**

(an aside, too bad the fortnightly challenges don't say when they expire)

---

Hmm, the calorie consumption numbers are for food, which humans are not good at digesting, does anyone have glucose/ATP consumption figures for human beings?  Maybe how much are people who're on IV drip fed?

Comment: Each challenge lasts for two weeks from the time it is posted on Meta.

Comment: Another question is *why* people would engineer humans to use photosynthesis.  Anyone who could afford the procedure could afford food anyway, and most people [like eating](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2003-03-11).

Comment: @TomAnderson As an example: In the *Old Man's War* trilogy, the genetically engineered bodies of the soldiers feature chloroplasts in order to supplement, rather than replace energy intake from food. This is done in order to provide extra or emergency energy for fighting.

Answer (score 14):

Well, there's a reason animals run around and eat plants, and not the other way around. Let's find out why:

Step 1: **Inbound solar radiation** in the vacuum at Earth orbit is 1,413 $W/m^2$, or about 1500 $W/m^2$

Step 2: **Photosynthetic efficiency** is [2% to 5% at best](http://www.fao.org/docrep/w7241e/w7241e05.htm#1.2.1), under optimal conditions. (I've seen estimates as low as 0.1%)  Let's use a wildly optimistic 5%.

Step 3: Estimate [**humanoid body area** to 1.5-2](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=39851) $m^2$. Let's round up to 2, and say half of it, or $1 m^2$, can face the sun at a given time.

Step 4: Estimate average [**daily food intake**](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/wecan/healthy-weight-basics/balance.htm) of a moderately active man to be around 2600 Calories, or $1.1\times10^7 J$, so round down to around 10 million Joules. Keep in mind that a Joule is a Watt/second.

Step 5: (My favorite) **Calculate** the energy capture formula as a function of energy inflow, area, efficiency and time:
$1500 W/m^2 \times 1m^2 \times 0.05 \times 1s = 75 W/s$

So at that wildly optimistic conversion rate under perfect sunlight you'd need, um, 133,333 seconds to power up for the day. That would be not half an hour, not 3 hours, but **37 hours**.

Keep in mind that in reality, even at noon, only about 1000-1100 Watts/sq. meter actually reach the ground (some get dissipated in the atmosphere), far less than half the body area will have direct solar incidence, and typical photosynthetic efficiency might actually be closer to 1%.

So unless you come up with a way to increase the surface area about 10-fold at least, it's looking a little difficult. You might consider placing your green men in the focal center of a set of reflecting mirrors. Might get a tad hot, though, and photosynthesis has an [optimal temperature range](http://fhs-bio-wiki.pbworks.com/w/page/12145771/Factors%20effecting%20the%20rate%20of%20photosynthesis).

Comment: There's room for improved efficiency with artificial / engineered photosynthesis (I mean, theoretically).  That could be where that 3-hour figure originally quoted comes from - if you had 25% efficiency say (you get some the rest of the day too).

Comment: Man, that would totally have to be engineered - the numbers for natural efficiency are actually like .3%

Comment: @Dan Smolinske: Is there really room for improved efficiency?  Plants have been experimenting with photosynthesis for what, a couple billion years?  With strong pressure (I can make more seeds, outcompete all my neighbors, and dominate the world!) for improvement, yet 3-6% (per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency ) is the best they've come up with.  Maybe that's about the best sunlight->food conversion possible?

Comment: @jamesfq One problem with genetic evolution in general is it can reach what is called a "false peak" - in other words, maybe to get really good efficiency you'd first need a series of mutations that would *reduce* efficiency, before finally arriving at a much better overall solution.  That means that it gets stuck - the necessary mutations are being selected against, unless all of them happen at once (which is very unlikely).  Artificial genetic manipulation can cut across that potential gap.

Comment: @Dan Smolinske: Certainly that's a theoretical possibility, but AFAIK no one has come close to demonstrating a more efficient sunlight->food conversion pathway, or even suggesting how one might work.

Comment: So solar panels instead of photosynthesis? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109739/is-plant-photosynthesis-more-efficient-than-solar-panels

Comment: @jamesqf We don't have atomic-scale engineering (yet), so producing sugars is limited to Mother Nature - when we've got the technology, I expect a lot better than what's evolved.  You could look at, say, algae farming with lights powered by 40% efficiency solar cells.  It might be more efficient if we harvest the sunlight, and re-purpose it into the spectrum that chlorophyll wants.

Comment: For photosynthetic efficiency: the numbers are slightly misleading as that IIRC assumes generation of sugar and carbohydrates then used to grow the plant. A photosynthetic animal would eat to grow and only use photosynthesis to "charge batteries". No idea how big a difference that would make, but it would be more efficient than producing sugar from carbon dioxide and water. Depends on the unknown energy storage compound.

Comment: @VilleNiemi, You do know that our 'batteries' are ATP which is sysntesized from glucose, which is a sugar, right?

Comment: @user3082: Re "You could look at, say, algae farming with lights powered by 40% efficiency solar cells."  Yes, and I could have invested my life savings with Bernie Madoff :-)  You can claim that something better _might_ be invented, and I wouldn't deny the possibility.  I just want to see a working prototype before I invest.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa I am not sure of the relevance. The battery I was talking about was something that could regenerate used ATP as needed and then be itself regenerated later using photosynthesis. The entire point was that this could feasibly be simpler and more efficient than synthesizing sugars. In this scenario ATP would be recycled so less sugar (and food in general) would be needed. Or was your point that sugar would be most likely and simplest battery compound anyway?

Comment: @VilleNiemi, please read the basics on aerobic respiration and metabolism, this is not something that I can expound at length in a comment thread.

Comment: That's Watt seconds (Ws), not Watt/second (W/s). Note that in your calculation you multiply with time. (Note however that W/m² is correct.)