# Plants or animals lighter than air

Tags: flora, atmosphere, fauna

Would it be possible for plants or animals to evolutionarily develop a trait to accumulate molecular hydrogen in their body cavities (produced for instance by electrolysis of water) so as to become lighter than air and to be constantly flying or "floating" in the atmosphere?

How might such animals and plants feed themselves? Would they consume birds and insects or maybe pollen and seeds/fluff of land plants?

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11208/are-flying-plants-possible]

Comment: Density in air is a tricky thing. Getting molecular hydrogen isn't easy, and electrolysis isn't very efficient. No real use for a plant. An animal might do so in oxygen poor environments...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Could be useful for a plant to get above a canopy or to spread its seeds.

Comment: @Samuel at least plants already use helicopter's principle: http://www.vitusltd.ru/V-images/acer_platanoides4.jpg

Comment: @Anixx For **falling**, not flying. Think of the dispersal range spreading helicopter seeds from a mile up.

Comment: Dandelions disperse seeds that way. Light seeds with parachutes are a lot more efficient than limited lighter than air flight. Working on an answer for animals that involves alternative dragons... :)

Comment: How do we even know that each and every micro-organism that floats in air is denser than air. There could already exist such a creature as the one you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible but probably not practical.

Looking at the method by which they might obtain hydrogen: you suggest electrolysis. This is certainly possible, though its efficiency is limited. The overall $ \Delta H $ (energy change) for this reaction is:

$$ H_2O \text{ } \unicode{x2192} \text{ } H_2 + \frac{1}{2}O_2 $$
$$ -285.83 \text{kJ} \text{ } \unicode{x2192} \text{ } 0 + 0 $$
$$ \Delta H = 285.83 \text{kJ} $$

<sup>[Source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/electrol.html)</sup>

This essentially means that you have to put 285.83 kilojoules of energy **in** to get one mole of hydrogen **out**.

Taking some numbers from [here](http://www.airships.net/helium-hydrogen-airships) and [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=1000+cubic+feet+to+cubic+meters), we see that 1 mole of hydrogen can lift 0.027kg, or 27g. If we're thinking of a little flower here, that's entirely possible: 1 mole of hydrogen can lift that weight ***on our planet***. (If your planet is smaller, the gravitational constant is lower and the hydrogen can lift more mass). There is still the *slight* problem that 1 mole of hydrogen takes has a volume of 24 litres... so the plant is either really big with thin walls or it explodes under the pressure.

Could the plant produce enough energy to create that amount of hydrogen? Yes - one mole of glucose going through respiration [produces a $ \Delta H $ of -2880kJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration#Aerobic_respiration), meaning the reaction is exothermic or releases energy. The average plant easily goes through 1 mole of glucose in less than a day - so as long as this plant doesn't require any more that a full load every day, it can be done. You just have to reshape your plants a bit.

As for the evolution of this trait, I'm not so sure - I'll leave it to someone more biologically knowledgeable than me to divine why the plant would need this ability.

---

Animals are a very different matter. I'm not going to go into them in this answer but essentially the same principles apply - but they're significantly heavier and thus would need a **lot** more hydrogen.