# Feasibility of a species based on Nyarlethotep (of HP Lovecraft lore)

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology

Nyarlethotep (the crawling chaos, the evil with a thousand forms, the messenger of the outer gods) originates from the literature of HP Lovecraft and is by far one of the most evil, sadistic, and interactive with humanity. Like I said in the last question, which was ([feasibility of yog sothoth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/166675/)), I will remove the god-like attributes and try to make it into a species.

In the future, humanity has found thousands of worlds filled with thousands of species and have encountered various space fairing creatures. However, one of the most interesting species humanity has encountered are the nyarlethotepians, or nyarlethoteps for short.

**appearance and behavior**

The appearance of nyarlethoteps varies drastically based on the species that is viewing them. To more advance alien races, nyarlethoteps look like highly advanced machines; to humans, nyarlethoteps look just like humans; to less advanced species, they will take the form of their gods. However, it is believed that the creatures actually have the form that involves 3 to 4 large tentacle-like appendages at the bottom, with having a upper torso that is vaguely humanoid and seemingly have another tentacle-like appendage for a head with a massive orifice in the center, which is presumed to be the mouth of the creature.

The species' individuals seemingly derive enjoyment and pleasure from the suffering, failure, and downfall of other known space-fairing creatures, but seem to derive the most enjoyment from humanity’s failures. Scientist and historians theorize that these species may have been the inspiration of humanity’s various religions and beliefs and may have inspired other known alien religions.

**intelligence**

These species are so intelligent such that human scientists speculate that a mere human trying to comprehend their vast knowledge will breakdown in existential fear, anxiety, and a newfound nihilistic outlook on life.

This species is advanced enough to traverse to other universes, build entire star systems, create bodies, transfer their consciousness to those new bodies, and much more. Surprisingly enough, these advanced beings do have a single belief in two gods: the yog sothoths and the azathoths. It is unknown why such advanced beings believe they are ruled by one more advanced race and by one more primitive race.

**extra facts**

A recent research exchange between these creatures and humanity has suggested that they do need to eat and drink, but it isn’t as much as a worry as it is for humans. Evidence suggest that the home world of these creatures only has cephalopod-like animals and is riddled with crevices, mountains, and valleys that allow for some creatures to hide in tight spaces.

Could such alien species feasibility exist, if not, then what **is** feasible?

Comment: My understanding is that you're asking if sadistic spacefaring squid could exist. Why couldn't they? I feel like the answer is a pretty straightforward "they couldn't pop into existence from human beliefs and they can't have magic eldritch properties but space squids make sense evolutionarily". Can you clarify what you want to examine in particular?

Comment: Human knowledge is already so vast that a mere human trying to understand it all would realize how insignificantly irrelevant we are in the universe. Why would your squid even derive enjoyment from watching humans suffer. Surely such predictable actions would be so boring and fleeting for a super intelligent race capable of manipulating entire galaxies.

Comment: "nyarlethotepians, or nyarlethoteps" <<< The first term implies that they come from a place known as "Nyarlethotep". You'd need to have a reason why we would have named their world after a god of chaos before we encountered them. The latter term would be if we named them after going to the world. I mention this only to help your story... I would get rid of the first term, because it breaks believability, unless you're also designing a planet that, from space, would inspire the name.

Comment: Problem phrase "these species may have been a direct result of humanity’s various religions and beliefs, and maybe even other known alien religions." Did you intend to say that humanity caused these creatures to exist? Or did you mean to say that these creatrures were the source material for humanity's religions? Right now, you have it that humanity's beliefs are somehow driving these creatures' evolution, which is highly implausible and going to be hard to explain scientifically.

Comment: In the question, I tried to say that the aliens have caused lesser developed alien species to form religions around them, sense lesser developed alien species wouldn’t be able to tell the difference between magic and advanced technology

Comment: @SRM "*You'd need to have a reason why we would have named their world after a god of chaos before we encountered them*" depends if in the fictional world the fiction that includes Nyarlathotep exists. Even then - scientists have named [creatures](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidbressan/2019/04/10/430-million-year-old-fossil-of-sea-creature-named-after-lovecrafts-cthulhu-mythos/) or even [shapes](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/sirsid.htm) after Lovecraftian entities. Surely, it's not a stretch that other scientists would also be nerds.

Comment: @RotNDecay I thought so. I just edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

**If the universe is populated as you suggest, then it is possible, but begs the question why**

If civilisations elsewhere exist, they are more likely to be much further advanced or not advanced than us, than they are similar to us. In actual fact, it could be likely that they are so much more advanced that they may not even notice us, like we don't tend to notice bacteria in our day-to-day lives so often.

If they are so 'in sync' with us that they do notice us, perhaps the outcome could be a sadistic one as you suggest, however if this is the case I am unsure why they would devote such energy to such a purpose when there is a wealth of other creatures in the universe, some of which are much more challenging than your average bacteria-worth human. If they like evil so much to harm us sadistically, it calls their rationality into question.

Lovecraft however excels in 'nameless fear'. In a way, *it is the feeling of dread* of something we do not understand. This is a familiar fear, and we don't need to look further than our recent history, or even the irrationality of ourselves, to realise that sadism is ever-present in our own thoughts (even to the point of being anti-rational, look at Nazi's, violent extremists and other relatively recent examples including institutionalised evil).

One of the **greatest fears is humanity, no matter how enlightened, would still be drawn to barbarism**. *This, I think, is the real message*, and unfortunately far more likely than an externalised evil represented by an alien species.

Comment: This answer does not address how the species appears different to different viewers, which is one of the hardest aspects that I see to explain scientifically. There's also the matter of humanity's beliefs shaping these creatures' evolution, which (you can read the comments) I've asked the author to explain. At least the first of these issues should be addressed in your answer.

Comment: OK... you don't have to worry about the second issue... OP has clarified that it is the aliens inspiring religion, not the other way around.